# Finding the volume of a wedge by integrating the area of vertical cross sections

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Would anyone please help me solve and explain this question. This question was one of the questions on my calc book that didn't have an answer nor a solution for. I want to know how to do it, but the book is not offering that (unless I buy the solution key, which I can't afford). I hope you guys can help; here is the question

**Find the volume of [the wedge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1RvN.png) by integrating the area of vertical cross sections. Note that vertical cross sections are right triangles the height and base of which depend on how far the cross section is from the origin.**

Please forgive me if I missed something out, I am new to this website and I just wish someone could help with this problem.

**Update:** Here is what I did:

```
The line from 4 to 8 is given by the equation (z/4)+(x/8) = 1 and the line
from 8 to 6 is given by (y/6)+(x/8) = 1. The cross sections perpendicular
to the x-axis are right triangles with height 4(1 - x/8) and base b(1 - x/8).
Thus, we have:
Integral (1/2)4*6(1 - x/a)^2 dx (with limit = 0 to limit = 8) = 1/6 * (6*4*8) = 32
```

What I am not very sure about is the first steps before taking the integral! Would any one explain it further in details, and relate it to how we get the answer? I hope that adds to the question.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Could you share your thoughts and efforts on the problem ?. You are more likely to receive help if you do so.

Comment: Observe that, the larger is $x$, the smaller is the section, thus consider that the surface of this section has something to do with $8-x$ or $(8-x)^2$. (The overall result is 32).

Comment: @Shailesh Thank you. I added what you suggested. Sorry for that

Comment: @JeanMarie would you please give a step by step explanation, so I can get the idea correctly. I am a little bit struggling with the first part of the problem (before taking the integral).

Comment: Project the moving triangle on $yz$ plane. The base area is 12. Thus the area of the moving triangle is within a factor of proportionality of $(\dfrac{8-x}{8})^2$ with this value (for example, when $x=5$, the factor of proportionality of areas is $1/4$). It remains to compute $\int_0^8  12 (\dfrac{8-x}{8})^2 dx$.

Comment: Replace $x=5$ by $x=4$ in my previous post.

Comment: @JeanMarie would you write it as a an answer below, with the full solution, so I can mark your answer. Thanks again

Comment: OK, I am going to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Project the moving triangle on the $yz$ plane. This projection preserves areas.

We are now faced with a 2D issue with a moving line. The base triangle has area 12.

The ratio of the area of the moving triangle and the base triangle is equal to the "shrinking" factor

$$f(x)=\left(\dfrac{8-x}{8}\right)^2$$

(for example, if $x=4$, the surface is shortened by a factor $f(4)=1/4$).

It remains to compute the volume of the wedge (or tetrahedron) as the integral of the area of its sections:

$$\int_0^8  12 f(x) dx = 32.$$